# I'm using boost::spirit to write a parser lexer

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, lexer, boost-spirit

I'm using boost::spirit to write a parser, lexer

here is what i want to do. i want to put functions and classes into data structures with the variables they use. so i want to know what would be the best way to do this.

and what parts of boost::spirit would be best to use for this?

the languages i want to use this on are C/C++/C#/Objective C/Objective C++.

also the language I'm writing it in is C++ only i'm not to good with the other languages i know

Comment: Those are 5 distinct language, the latter four of which featuring very extensive and mutually exclusive extensions to the already not-too-shabby first. To top it off, at least two of them are notoriously hard to parse, and even parsing C isn't a task you hand a beginner. Basically, if you have to ask this question you should switch to an easier project. Lisp (S-expression) is fairly simple (but by no means trivial) from a parsing perspective.

Comment: I'll look into this i would like to use boost::spirit though.

Comment: Like delnan said, if you have to ask then this is probably over your head. However, I am quite the fan of either making your parser by hand or using ANTLR.

Comment: Don't forget preprocessing. Of course there's Boost Wave if you're really in for a good time :)

Comment: The short answer is "none". Spirit just isn't suited to these languages (or vice versa, if you prefer). A much more reasonable starting point would be [clang](http://clang.llvm.org).

Comment: I have reviewed the idea of using clang but there is one problem. I need the system to not preprocess any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spirit is a fine tool, but it is not the best tool for all parsing tasks. And for the task of parsing actual C++, it is pretty terrible.

Spirit excels at small-to-mid-level parsing tasks. Language that are fairly regular, with standardized grammars and so forth. C and C-derived languages are generally too complicated for Spirit to handle. It's not that you *can't* write Spirit parsing code for them. It's just that doing so would be too difficult to build and maintain, given Spirit's general design.

I would suggest downloading [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/index.html) if you want a good C or C++ (or Objective variants thereof) parser. It is a compiler as well, but it's designed to be modular, so you can just link to the parsing part of it.

Comment: I have found libparser and other from the source code is there any good documentation for this?